# How to install iconv-devel on CentOS 5.6?

Tags: centos, rvm, iconv, yum

After [installing rvm](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) on CentOS 5.6 and run `rvm notes`:

```
dependencies:
  # For RVM
  rvm: yum install -y bash curl git # NOTE: For git you need the EPEL repository enabled

  # For Ruby (MRI & Ree) you should install the following OS dependencies:
  ruby: yum install -y gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel ;
        yum install -y make bzip2 ;
        yum install -y iconv-devel # NOTE: For centos 5.4 final iconv-devel might not be available :(
```

However `iconv-devel` cannot be found:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package iconv-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

How can I install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to worry about it on CentOS 5.4+ (and some other Red Hat-based systems).

It's already provided in the glibc library:

- http://www.kannel.org/pipermail/users/2008-August/005444.html
- [Error when trying to run gem install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345795/error-when-trying-to-run-gem-install)