# Error when trying to run gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to get rails up and running on my development server. It's a fedora14 box. I installed rvm, ruby 1.8.7, and rubygems 1.6.2. When I try to install rails via gem, `gem install rails`, i get the following error:

```
ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR: While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

Any ideas as to what is going on. I'm 100% new to ruby/rubygems/rails and I know enough about Linux to be dangerous so any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Run `rvm notes` and install whatever it tells you (`zlib-devel` will probably be one of the packages you'll need to install via `yum`). The output you'll see will be similar to this:

```
  # For Ruby (MRI & Ree) you should install the following OS dependencies:
  ruby: yum install -y gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel ;
        yum install -y make bzip2 ;
        yum install -y iconv-devel # NOTE: For centos 5.4 final iconv-devel might not be available :(
```

Comment: I got everything installed but iconv-devel. Said there was no package. Still getting the same error after all the other packages have been installed

Comment: After doing it, make sure to recompile/reinstall ruby. `rvm remove 1.8.7` and then `rvm install 1.8.7`.

Comment: Also, on some RedHat-based systems, `iconv-devel` won't be available -- don't worry about it.

Comment: @Dylan Markow： So, what is the substitution for `iconv-devel` on RedHat-based OS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the zlib libraries.  A gem is trying to use it with a C extension but it is not found.  http://fr.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=zlib-devel&system=&arch=  Install zlib-devel.

Comment: I installed zlib-devel-1.2.5-2.fc14.i686 but still same errors

Answer (score 0):

What this error means is that zlib library is missing. This is a common problem and if you google for it, you'd find loads of information on the same. In ubuntu (where I work) installing the package zlib1g-dev and zlib1g fixes it. I am not sure what the equivalent package in Fedora is, but you should be able to search / find that.